# Starting of speech recognition takes a long time

Tags: android, speech-recognition

I'm using the SpeechRecognizer class from Android to implement a continues speech recognition in android. 
My problem is that sometimes the starting of the recognition (time between fireing the intent and getting the onReadyForSpeech callback) takes a long long time. In a few cases more than 1 minute!

Do anybody know this problem?

**Starting the recognition:**

```
    Intent recognizerIntent = new Intent(
            RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM); 

    SpeechRecognitionUtil.recognizeSpeechDirectly(context,
            recognizerIntent, this, getSpeechRecognizer());

private SpeechRecognizer getSpeechRecognizer() {
    if (recognizer == null) {
        recognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(context);
    }
    return recognizer;
}

public static void recognizeSpeechDirectly(Context context,
        Intent recognizerIntent, RecognitionListener listener,
        SpeechRecognizer recognizer) {
    // need to have a calling package for it to work
    if (!recognizerIntent.hasExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE)) {
        recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE,
                "com.dummy");
    }

    recognizer.setRecognitionListener(listener);
    recognizer.startListening(recognizerIntent);
}
```

Sometimes the following callback is called about a minute after starting recognition!

```
@Override
public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle params) {}
```

**LOG**

```
06-24 20:18:28.266: I/WordActivator(26139): recognizeSpeechDirectly
06-24 20:18:51.091: D/WordActivator(26139): ready for speech Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=4]
```

Comment: Nope. And with no code and no reported error it is impossible to tell.

Comment: I it's because of the network latency. The voice recognition is done on the cloud

Comment: I don't think the problem is caused by the network latency, because it also occurs in offline mode!